# mysql_num_row com inner join

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner

Tenho 2 tabelas:

1. Leads
2. Lojas

O relacionamento é o seguinte:
1 loja -> N leads

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso listar o número de leads cadastrados para cada loja e depois ordenar por ordem decrescente para saber qual loja possui mais leads

O inner join que estou usando duplica as lojas quando executa a query. HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
SELECT nome_loja, uf, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads 
                               WHERE loja_selecionada = nome_loja) AS 'total'
FROM lojas ORDER BY total DESC
```

Também da certo. =)

**[Veja funcionando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/549032/2)**

Comment: ANIMAL! Parabéns, era exatamente isso! Obrigado!

Comment: só fiz uma mudança do order by para o total e show!! tks brow

Comment: @LéoKovaski... XD ... Tranquilo!

Answer (score 2):

seria algo mais ou menos assim?

```
SELECT COUNT(le.id) AS total_leads FROM leads AS le
INNER JOIN lojas AS lo ON le.id_loja = lo.id
GROUP BY lo.id
ORDER BY lo.id DESC
```

Comment: Cara, perfeito!!!!! Me retornou certinho!Só que não apareceu o NOME_LOJA no resultado final. Como adiciono isso?

Comment: tenta colocar algo como: SELECT COUNT(le.id) AS total_leads, nome_loja.... Vê se funciona.

Comment: Aliás, no caso, você quer o nome da loja e o total de lojas? Me explica direito essa parte.